# while validating in cakephp, what 'validate'=>'first' does?

Tags: php, validation, cakephp, model

I have written in my code like this...

```
$this->User->saveAll($this->data, array('validate'=>'first'));
$this->User->saveAll($this->data, array('validate'=>false));
```

'validate'=>false will not check for validations in model. But if I replace false with first, then what will it do?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From http://book.cakephp.org/view/75/Saving-Your-Data

> validate: Set to false to disable validation, true to validate each record before saving, **'first' to validate *all* records before any are saved**, or 'only' to only validate the records, but not save them.

Comment: Thanks Gordon. really helpful.